# Tendermint error-BigchainDB network: "Connection refused"

Tags: tendermint, bigchaindb

I'm trying to set up a local BigchainDB network with three Raspberry Pis using this repository as a reference: *[BigchainDB Ansible deployment recipes](https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb-node-ansible)*

However, all my nodes encounter a connection refused problem on *tendermint.service*. Tendermint is on v0.31.5 and BigchainDB on v2.0.0.

I checked if the port is blocked, but it seems to be fine. The error that I am getting is:

> Jan 09 14:52:41 ubuntu tendermint[807]: E[2023-01-09|14:52:41.985] abci.socketClient failed to connect to tcp://0.0.0.0:26658.  Retrying... module=abci-client connnt failed to connect to tcp://0.0.0.0:26658.  Retrying... module=abci-client connection=query err="dial tcp 0.0.0.0:26658: connect: connection refused"

I am running Tendermint using a unit file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Tendermint. Byzantine-fault tolerant state machine replication.
Documentation=https://tendermint.readthedocs.io/en/master/

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/tendermint node \
                   --p2p.laddr "tcp://0.0.0.0:26656" \
                   --proxy_app="tcp://0.0.0.0:26658" \
                   --consensus.create_empty_blocks=false \
                   --p2p.pex=false
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu
User=tendermint
Group=bigchaindb

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've also configured the *genesis.json* file on every node:

```json
{
 "genesis_time": "2022-12-19T11:03:38.312591884Z",
 "chain_id": "test-chain-sveGDu",
 "consensus_params": {
  "block": {
   "max_bytes": "22020096",
   "max_gas": "-1",
   "time_iota_ms": "1000"
  },
  "evidence": {
   "max_age": "100000"
  },
  "validator": {
   "pub_key_types": [
    "ed25519"
   ]
  }
 },
 "validators": [
  {
   "address": "87498C9693362176BFC2A4122133568297865193",
   "pub_key": {
    "type": "tendermint/PubKeyEd25519",
    "value": "dIy8HUovVJatppDrmJieSGW26jWSJrNhzwHMJetysqA="
   },
   "power": "10",
   "name": ""
  },
  {
   "address": "B59216978AB15F31171E8AB482F62D768721DA13",
   "pub_key": {
    "type": "tendermint/PubKeyEd25519",
    "value": "64BTBlnCPSe26HJfpnCkV8A6BS5w//rAqVu/C01sOqA="
   },
   "power": "10",
   "name": ""
  },
  {
   "address": "6067D6D53CD82EBF9C1F4704AC9F27BAE7CB8F9F",
   "pub_key": {
    "type": "tendermint/PubKeyEd25519",
    "value": "QGNyJpLgqjlRanNgtRdAsLTnpylmSo9FymkPFXSnZbI="
   },
   "power": "10",
   "name": ""
  }
 ],
 "app_hash": ""
}
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure if this question is [on-topic](/help/on-topic) here. Did you already read the the Help Center page on what questions are on-topic here? If so, can you explain to my why this is on topic? (since I'm not sure). If not, please read it and consider whether your question is on-topic here. If you're not sure where to ask this question, you can ask on meta.stackexchange.com using the \[site-recommendation\] tag.

Comment: I was not sure about the question being on-topic but since it's a software tool is it not alright to ask here? Thank you for the guidance and the references!

Comment: Not all software tool questions are on-topic here on SO. For it to be on-topic here on SO, it generally needs to be commonly or primarily used by programmers. For example, build-tooling, VCS, containerization, and package-management tools are on-topic, but video-editing, 3d-graphics, and GIS generally are not. Those may have their own SE network sites, such as [video.se], [blender.se], and [gis.se].

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385666/where-to-ask-about-tendermint-connection-refused-error).